# Can I did this command pattern if I declare the operator how it were a variable?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This my code:

```
const addition = (num1, num2) => num1 + num2;

const subtraction = (num1, num2) => num1 - num2;

const multiplication = (num1, num2) => num1 * num2;

const division = (num1, num2) => num1 / num2;

const command = {
  add: addition,
  subtract: subtraction,
  multiply: multiplication,
  division,
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return this[action](num1, num2);
  }
};

const calculate = (action, numbers) => {
  const result = command.execute(action, numbers);
  console.log(
    `In ${action} of numbers ${Object.values(numbers)} the result is ${result}`
  );
};

calculate('add', { num1: 2, num2: 3 });
```

It is the command pattern that I did but I think if it could be the command like this or something that you declare operator to execute after to depend of action:

```
const command = {
  add: '+',
  subtract: '-',
  multiply: '*',
  division: '/',
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return num1 this[action] numb2;
  }
};
```

My question if this would be possible or the first code is good?

Because I see all the function in command is very similar the only change of the functions is the operator

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; please review the question title. Have also a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: can you add an example of the use case and the wanted result?

Answer (score 1):

> if this would be possible or the first code is good?

It is possible and the first code is good

For the second code block to be possible you'll need `eval`, which is **to be avoided and not recommended**:

```js
const command = {
  add: '+',
  subtract: '-',
  multiply: '*',
  division: '/',
  execute: function(action, { num1, num2 }) {
    return eval(`${num1} ${this[action]} ${num2}`);
  }
};

console.log( command.execute('add', {num1: 5, num2: 6}) );
```

Comment: why is eval() not recommended?

Comment: @RaúlBarrios check this for more details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!